# select2 not working inside fieldset element

Tags: jquery-select2, fieldset

select2 not working inside fieldset element
using elements jQuery v3.2.1, Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Gender </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control gender-select">
                <optgroup label="Developer">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Designer">
                    <option value="WY">Peter</option>
                    <option value="WY">Hanry Die</option>
                    <option value="WY">John Doe</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```